# How can I find differences between a nested array and array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to compare an array of objects with a nested array and get the differences.
I often struggle with filtering so what I've already tried just returned either the whole array or undefined results.

Here's some examples on what my data looks like:

```
  const groups = [
    {
      name: "Team Rocket",
      managerId: "abc",
      members: ["1"]
    },
    {
      name: "The Breakfast Club",
      managerId: "def",
      members: [],
    }
  ];
```

```
  const users = [
    {
      name: "Jessie",
      userId: "1"
    },
    {
      name: "John",
      userId: "2"
    }
  ]
```

In this case I want to compare userId from users with the items in the members array (end result should be John's data).

Example of what I've tried:

```
  const userWithNoGroup = users.filter((user) => {
    return !groups.some((group) => {
      return user.userId === group.members;
    });
  });
```

Currently it returns all users.
I think the code above would work if members wasn't a nested array, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just missed the last step you trie to compare a userId with a array of userIds `user.userId === group.members`

Just use the `some` as you used before or `includes`.

```js
    return group.members.some((member) => member === user.userId);
    // Or use the includes method
    return group.members.includes(user.userId);
```

Comment: You've freed me from filtering hell! Thank you so much Disco, this worked perfectly! :D

Answer (score 1):

You could get all the uniquer users who are part of a group to a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Then, use `filter` to get all the users who are not par of the `Set`.

```js
const groups = [{name:"Team Rocket",managerId:"abc",members:["1"]},{name:"The Breakfast Club",managerId:"def",members:[]}],
      users = [{name:"Jessie",userId:"1"},{name:"John",userId:"2"}],
      set = new Set( groups.flatMap(a => a.members) ),
      output = users.filter(u => !set.has(u.userId));

console.log(output)
```

Comment: I had no idea you could filter it like this, thank you Adiga!